# When checking the Origin and Referer header for CSRF protection, does the scheme need to match as well?

Tags: csrf

I would have thought the domain name (including any subdomain) up through the trailing slash would be sufficient (like `subdomain.example.com/` or `subdomain.example.com:2082/`), but I have seen references to checking the scheme as well.

Comment: I don't see a vector, but it can't hurt. keep in mind https sites reject http connections...

Comment: Was getting false CSRF errors on sites that start as http and then change to https upon login. Wasn't sure if it was worth trying to code around this.

Comment: Agree with @dandavis - solely from the browser perspective I don't see using a scheme change to get CSRF. There *might* (and I'm uncertain here) be a context with custom schemes via compromised desktop or mobile app.

Comment: @user18519: there's all kinds of vectors from such non-SOP useragents, but these aren't CSRF by definition, and such apps _should_ not have cookie access anyway...